# Reporting Service (SSRS) : Report Footer is not working when exported to excel

Tags: reporting-services, report, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, reportbuilder3.0

I am using reporting service 2008 for create report and I found the problem about export excel. The problem is as follows :

1. Report Footer is not working when exported to excel. How I can render footer when export to excel.
2. When I print an excel. Footer font size larger than I custom font size from report builder

Please help me.

Comment: How are you setting up your Report Footer?

Answer (score 1):

Footers are exported to excel, however when opening the file initially, you won't see the footers in the "Normal" Workbook view. To view the footer, you could switch to "Page Layout" view under the view menu in excel.